# additionalAdTargetingParams for playlist player?

Tags: brightcove

When using a single video player, I can successfully pass in additionalAdTargetingParams with values targeted at the ad server (ex: VERTICAL, PARTNER, etc).  These values are based on a single video's metadata. But when using a playlist player, I am not clear on how this same video-level detail can be passed for an ad call every timery time  a new video is played.

I know one option could be to fake the playlist experience using a single video player and thumbnails, but I feel like there should be a way to do this for each video inside the playlist and I'm just not seeing it yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key-values can be set for videos in the Advertising module of Video Cloud Studio, but if you want to set them dynamically, you can use the setAdPolicy() API of the player.

Documentation for the setAdPolicy() API:
http://developer.brightcove.com/en/articles/dynamic-ad-policies-using-setadpolicy-api

This API will allow you to set key-values for each video as it plays. Get a copy of the current ad policy using getAdPolicy(), listen for the MediaEvent.CHANGE (triggered when a new video has been selected), modify the object as you wish (i.e. changing key-values), and then setAdPolicy() using the new object.

Currently, this is a Flash-only API. For HTML5, you might consider the single video player experience you mentioned.

The player also includes the playlist as a key-value automatically. From the ad server, you can target the playlist ID directly as a key-value without any code required (although this doesn't match the use case exactly with VERTICAL, PARTNER, as your desired flags):
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/key-value-pairs-passed-video-cloud

Comment: I've been using the video cloud for over a year but hadn't noticed that you could manipulate key/values at the video level. I'm seeing adKeys now & I could set those via the media API but that data already exists in our CMS. But I will take a look into the setAdPolicy - Thanks!